# Windows service installation and starting inside another service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a host app installed as win service. This host supports installing plugins in own domains. Domains enabled with assembly shadow copying. Essentially plugins are also win services. So during the plugin installation there are following stages:

1. Create domain, shadow load plugin's assembly
2. Instantiate plugin's service with dependency injection
3. Perform service installation
4. Start plugin's service

Third and fourth stages:

```
public class ServiceCommander : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public Exception InstallWinService()
    {
        var assembly = service.GetType().Assembly;
        var account = AccountStore.GetAccount().Split(' ');
        var installer = new AssemblyInstaller(assembly, 
            new [] { $"/user={account[0]}", $"/password={account[1]}", $"/LogFile={TracksSinkHost.InstallLogPath}" });
        try
        {
            installer.UseNewContext = true;
            installer.Install(null);
            installer.Commit(null);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            installer.Rollback(null);
            return new Exception(ex.Message) { Source = ex.Source }; 
        }
    }

    public Exception StartWinService(bool ignoreManualStartType = false)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(service);
            var serviceController = new ServiceController(service.ServiceName);
            if (serviceController.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running &&
                (serviceController.StartType == ServiceStartMode.Automatic || ignoreManualStartType))
                serviceController.Start();
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Exception(ex.Message) { Source = ex.Source };
        }
    }
}
```

where *service* object is ServiceBase

While all stages do succeed, fourth stage don't. *serviceController.Start()*  **immediately** throws *"service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."* Also I see in System Event log *"A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the service to connect."*

For me seems like Service Control Manager can't find plugin's entry point, so I provided Startup Object in plugin's project:

```
static class Program
{
    public static ServiceBase Service;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Service != null)
            ServiceBase.Run(Service);
    }
}
```

But Main never executed.

Also I see same Event Logs if start installed plugin's service manually or if I disable shadow copying on child domains. So whats wrong?

Comment: Does the new process actually start up?  (If you're not sure, Process Monitor might be a suitable troubleshooting tool.)  How is the new service configured, i.e., what does `sc qc` show?

Comment: I don't understand, why you already have "ServiceBase.Run(service)", but then start it again with ServiceController? Are you trying to start the service again (when it is being started)?

Comment: @HoàngLong: good point, I hadn't noticed that.  `ServiceBase.Run()` doesn't return until the service the current process is running stops, and isn't guaranteed to return at all (the process may simply be terminated) so while I'm not sure what the OP was trying to do, that code is definitely wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what your overally goal here is - you talk about shadow copying, but you are aware that once the service is registered, *Windows* is going to be responsible for starting the processes where the services run in the future, and it wont be creating app domains with shadow copying when it does that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you're absolutely right, I missed that  windows starts new process after  `serviceController.Start()` and expected it runs inside my bootstrapper process

Answer (score 0):

From the code, my guess is that it is trying to start a being-started service, therefore cause the exception.

To confirm, in `StartWinService` function, please log the status of `serviceController.Status`. I doubt that it could be currently `StartPending` as you already call `ServiceBase.Run(service)`

If it is correct, try removing the serviceController part.

Explanation: ServiceBase.Run() just register the service (aka: mark it for starting), so there's no guarantee that when you check the status with serviceController, your service has finished starting yet.